# Place text at the centre of right half of an image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place some text on top of a background image as the picture shown below, the text should be at the center of the right half of the image. Anyone know how to solve this?
[image]

html

```
<div class="full-width">
    <div class="text-center"><h2 class="text">text</h2></div>     
    <img src="img/example.jpg">

</div>
```

css

```
.text{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-top: 1em;


}

.full-width{
    width:100%;

}
```

some solutions in the comments shows result like this:

[image]

Comment: please share existing code and what you're tried so far...

Comment: use `position:absolute; top:50%; right:10%;`

Comment: @GoosvandenBekerom I will not worry about that. Can you show your best solution ever. so that i can argue with my solution.

Comment: why 10%? I want the text to always not go over the 50% boarder to the left half of the image,I don't think 10% will work in smaller screen.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai said 10% to the right, not from the left... it all depends on the size of your picture and the width of the text, there is no computation in css that would tell it to "center in the right half of the image"...

Comment: by the way, is it your problem that when you resize, the text moves? if it is the real issue here, make sure the parent container has `position:relative` set (at least)...

Comment: play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/bjun8ypp/

Answer (score 0):

If the text is NOT dinamic, you can always know what size the container will be (beign the container an inline-block element). Browsers may display the text slightly different so the size may change some pixels. This means this solution won't be 100% exact but close.

as you can see in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L5ky59rb/) the text container size is 148 x 27 (chrome) so then you just need to adjust your margins to set it right:

```
.text-center {
    position:absolute;
    left: 75%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left:-74px;
    margin-top:-27px;
    display:inline-block;}

.full-width{
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
```

where margin left is half of the container width.

Hope this may help you

Edited: or as Suresh suggested (much better idea) set a fixed width to text-center with text-align:center and, again, set the margin-left to minus half that width like in this  updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/L5ky59rb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this with absolute positioning of the text-element and a CSS transform.

By positioning the element `top:50%, left:75%`we push the top left corner of the element to 3/4 of the way over the width of the div (as defined by the image)...

Then we move the element left by half it's own with and up half it's own height ensuring that the center of the text element now exactly 75% left and 50% down/up.

This is acheieved with `transform:translate(-50%,-50%);

[**Full Page Jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lb16j6p5/5/embedded/result/)

**Note:** I have deliberately limited the width of the text element as extra long text can flow out of the wrapping div.

If you know that the text will not overflow, perhaps because you have only a couple of words, you can remove the `max-width` and set `white-space:nowrap;` (currently commented out) and the text will take it's own width.

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.full-width {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.text-center {
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    color:white;
    position: absolute;
    left:75%;
    top:50%;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:auto;
    text-align: center;
    max-width:25%; /* see note */
   /*white-space:nowrap; */
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%); 
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h2 class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor.</h2>
    </div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-250-4.jpg"/>
</div>

<div class="full-width">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h2 class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</h2>
    </div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-c-800-300-7.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my comments, I just give an idea not a exact solutions. Here is the exact solution what you have looking for.

```
 .full-width{position:relative; width:420px;}
 .text-center{position:absolute; top:50%; margin-top:-25px; right:25%; margin-right:-50px;}
 .text{padding:0; margin:0; width:100px; height:50px; border:1px solid #000;}
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/67zcr198/1/)